# Modal not popping out of Page when using Simple Form and Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

I'm building a ToDo app using a Tutorial on the web. I have reached a point where there is a modal for new todo tasks. I got the modal to work, but it looks nothing like a modal.

Here's how it looks now

[image: What it looks like]

And here is how it should look like

[image: Should look like this]

My code is as follows:
`new.js.erb` located in `views`>`tasks`

```
m = $('#modal');
m.html('<%= j(render partial: 'task_form', locals: {task: @task}) %>');
m.modal('show');
```

`_task_form.html.haml`located in `views` > `tasks`

```
.modal-header
  %h1 New Task
= simple_form_for task, class: 'clearfix' do |f|
  .modal-body
    = f.input :title
    = f.input :note
    = f.input :completed
  .modal-footer
    = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

My `Gemfile` looks like this:

```
ruby '2.5.1'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'haml'
gem "haml-rails"
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Can someone point out why I'm not able to see the modal as I want? Is it because of simple form or something else?

Thank you for your help!

P.S.Just to let you know that I'm a beginner and that it's my first time working with haml and JQuery in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

You modal is missing `.modal`, `.modal-dialog` and `.modal-content` classes which I believe is the reason for your problem. Try adding those to your modal

```
#modal.modal.fade{role: 'dialog', 'aria-labelledby': 'myModalLabel', 'aria-hidden': true}
  .modal-dialog{role: 'document'}
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        %h1 New Task
      = simple_form_for task, class: 'clearfix' do |f|
        .modal-body
          = f.input :title
          = f.input :note
          = f.input :completed
        .modal-footer
          = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```